# does tdengine support transfer data from influxdb to tdengine using line protocol

Tags: tdengine

I am using tdengine and influx-db, and i want to transfer data from influx db to tdengine. Since read the data from influxdb and then write to tdengine spent lot of time. I know that influxdb support schemaless and has it own line protocol.
Is there anyone know that  whether tdengine support influxdb's line protocol? If it does, could you please give some sample examples?

Answer (score 0):

yes,TDnengine support influxdb's line protocol, from version 2.3.0.0. From your description it seems that you want to use tdengine's schemaless insert example. There are various language examples, since TDengine support many language(java\c\C#\python\go\rust\node).This is example of
c:https://github.com/taosdata/TDengine/blob/develop/tests/examples/c/schemaless.c
You can find many other example in github under these links: https://github.com/taosdata/TDengine/blob/develop/tests/examples

Comment: Thank you, I wil read this. Can I use nodejs to do schemaless insert?

Comment: hope this can help you .https://github.com/taosdata/TDengine/blob/develop/src/connector/nodejs/test/testSchemalessInsert.js

Comment: yeah，this is helpful！